# C# Printer Local Printer installation Handling

Tags: c#, printing, wmi

I have a short question, maybe someone knows the answer.

At the moment If I want to add a printer from a printserver to the user, I can call the `AddPrinterConnection()`, 
and the printer will be added automatically and will be only visible for the user which has added the printer.
If I want to install a IP-Direct printer for everyone on the computer, I can use the `ManagementClass` in C#

But what if I don't have a printserver and want to install/add a IP-Direct printer only for one user (The other users should not be able to see the printer).

Does anyone know how to handle such a case?

Comment: you might have to use WMI

Comment: @BlooB 
Yea The WMI Win32_Printer class provies the AddPrinterConnection function.
So I already use WMI